# SAML for Native Mobile Apps(Android and IOS)

Tags: android, ios, saml-2.0, onelogin

I have been searching for quite long time, whether SAML Authentication available for Mobile Apps. I went through the oneLogin developer portal completely, but could not find any documents on Android and IOS Api.
 Can somebody please confirm me whether SAML gives support to Mobile Apps or not.

Comment: We have implement SAML in out mobile app, we just present to a WebView to the user. After login in we redirect to the app URL.

Comment: but what is the app URL since mobile app is not hosted on server right? What is your application URL exactly?

Comment: @rckoenes How will you get the SAML response in this case if you redirect to the web view ? Is there any delegate methods of WKWebView that provides the response info ?

Comment: We provide a callback url which we indeed detect with the `WKWebViewDelegate`

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I am seeking for the same solution

Comment: did anyone get a solution? I too want to implement SAML Based authentication in iOS/Android apps.

Answer (score 8):

Folks who go this route generally just implement a WebView and handle the SAML request that way.

Take a look at this article on Webviews as this will allow you to share information (notably any session you've established with an SSO provider) between native apps that also support SAML the same way.

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/09/01/sharing-web-data-wkwebview/

Basically, if you do this, you'll also be supporting SSO on mobile via SAML (or OpenID Connect, if you go that route)